# How to validate variable nested objects in jsonschema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to create a schema for a structure like this:

```json
{
    "DeviceControl": {
        "Commands": {
            "BitLength": 8,
            "Remark": "130=Restore device parameters to factory defaults,134=Calibrate gyro sensor,4=PDout come from IO-Link,128=PDout come from UART,165=Calibrate vacuum sensor,167=Reset erasable counter,168=Reset voltage min/max (Sensor & Actor) & Temperature,169=Reset vacuum min/max",
            "ParameterDescriptor": "130=Restore device parameters to factory defaults,134=Calibrate gyro sensor,4=PDout come from IO-Link,128=PDout come from UART,165=Calibrate vacuum sensor,167=Reset erasable counter,168=Reset voltage min/max (Sensor & Actor) & Temperature,169=Reset vacuum min/max",
            "Range": "130,134,4,128,165,167,168,169"
        }
    },
    "Parameter": {
        "Device Initial Settings": {
            "MPU calibrate value - Gyro X": {
                "Index": 303,
                "Label": "MPU calibrate value - Gyro X",
                "DataType": "IntegerT",
                "BitLength": 16
            },
            "MPU calibrate value - Gyro Y": {
                "Index": 304,
                "Label": "MPU calibrate value - Gyro Y",
                "DataType": "IntegerT",
                "BitLength": 16
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have, is that the schema of "BigLength, Remark, ParameterDescriptor, etc." I can define easily.
But how do I apply it to all objects until it finds this schema?
It can be anything deeply nested. When there are no more objects as children, it should apply this schema. It is impossible to define the fixed schema for all the object keys (`DeviceControl.Commands` or `Parameter.Device Initial Settings.MPU calibrate value - Gyro X`)

I also cannot change the JSON.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: If you don't know how deep the object will be, it's not possible to use JSON Schema to do your validation. Sorry.

Comment: @Relequestual I disagree - it should be possible to achieve with a recursive definition - e.g. `anyOf: [ ref-to-self, leaf-object-that-OP-cares-about ]`

Comment: The key in the question is "until it finds this schema". THAT cannot be done. If the "until" is not required, then yes, there's a viable approach. Jason has already answered below.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema handles recursive structures quite elegantly. If I understand your question properly, this should do the trick.

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    { ... leaf schema ... },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "": { "$ref": "#" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The first alternative declares the leaf and the second alternative is a branch, which can either be another branch or terminating at a leaf, recursing as far as necesary.

NOTE: Some people prefer to use `additionalProperties` instead of `patternProperties`. I prefer this despite it being a little more verbose because unlike `additionalProperties`, the validation behavior of `patternProperties` can not be modified by other keywords.

Comment: Recursive would be fine. I am trying this